# Is there anything like Netflix in Estonia?

Tags: webapp-rec

I recently moved from the US to Estonia. The thing I miss most is Netflix streaming; is anyone aware of a company that runs a similar service in Estonia or the baltics? I don't so much care about DVD delivery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use their streaming service from out of the country but if you are asking about DVD's by mail, I believe you are out of luck.

Comment: Hmm, I like this idea... I can't find anything saying either way, whether it's legal or illegal.

Answer (score 0):

I've received comments about people using Netflix from outside US, using a VPN into some US-based host. Anyone have a good link about it? I dont know if a proxy is enough or you need a full tunnel.

Also, dont know the legal status of this, even if you are a US citizen.

iTunes on the other hand dont limit you to acces their content from abroad (they do not check source IP), but they do requiere you to pay with a US based credit card (US billing address).